# FullCalendar changing event color based on view

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, fullcalendar

I'm trying to dynamically change my event colors based on the view that is being rendered in full calendar.

When I populate the events into the calendar with ajax I pass the color and textColor dynamically from the server.

```
        if event.service_area:
        if event.service_area.pk == 1:
            color = '#4986e7'
        elif event.service_area.pk == 2:
            color = '#ff7537'
        elif event.service_area.pk == 3:
            color = '#f691b2'
    else:
        color = '#00a19c'

    start = event.start_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    event_slug = {
        'title': event.summary,
        'start': start,
        'description': event.description,
        'location': event.location,
        'g_event_id': event.google_event_id,
        'status': event.status,
        'event_id': event.id,
        'color': '#fff',
        'textColor': color,
    }
```

In the 'month' view I want to retain the color that I originally passed in the event json (color text, white background), but when I switch to 'basicWeek' or 'agendaDay' view I want the colors to switch (white text, color background). When I switch views the first time it works, but then any subsequent switching of views causes the colors to endlessly switch.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (view !== 'month' ) {
      var color = event.color;
      var text = event.textColor;

      event.color = text;
      event.textColor = color;
    }
}
```

How can I set up this event render script to only switch the colors I originally passed when the view I'm changing from is 'month' to 'agendaDay' or 'basicWeek' and then revert to the original colors when switching back to the 'month' view?

Comment: add a class to element...and use css rules based on view classes

Answer (score 0):

You are using the colors on the wrong object.

From the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/):

> - **event** is the Event Object that is attempting to be rendered.
> - **element** is a newly created jQuery element that will be used for rendering. It has already been populated with the correct time/title text.

So, apply the colors to the **element** variable, not to the *event*. This way your original colors won't change in the actual **event** object, only in the rendered object.